# webpack - how to have different variable for production and development environment

Tags: javascript, webpack

Is it possible to have one variables that will be different on dev and production environments. What should I use to make that variable. Is testing for location url a good solution?

Comment: I'm wonder why you need to run webpack on production ? Isn't simpler option to push all bundled stuff to production, and keep webpack on development/staging ?

Comment: @Belmin I now move to have only bundled files for production but I still need to have in one of my files a variable that different on production and dev.

Answer (score 2):

In your `package.json` file, you can set environment variables in the
`script` section, like `NODE_ENV=production` for the `build` script in this example:

```
{
  "scripts": {
  "start": "npm run dev",
  "dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server ...",
  "build": "NODE_ENV=production ./node_modules/.bin/webpack -p --config webpack.production.config.js"
} ... }
```

Then, in your Javascript code you can test for it using the `process` global:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { ... } else { ... }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it will be understood by webpack when bundling your files